# Creating conditional sub-questions in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I have an initial (round 1) question, which asks user to select options (checkboxes) that applies to him/her.

There are total 5 checkbox options (#1, #2, #3, #4, #5). Out of the 5 options, let's assume that user selects #1, #3 and #4.

So now in the next round (round 2), I want Google Forms to present a set of detailed questions on topics #1, #3 and #4 only. I have already made sections consisting detailed questions for the 5 topics.

Basically, depending on the options that a user selects, I want Google Forms to present him/her with detailed round 2 questions on only those selected topics.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Google Forms only allows conditional navigation on Multiple Choice type questions. Thus, where to go next can only be based on one answer.

A possible way around this is to allow the user to choose a multiple choice answer, go to a section based on that answer, and, when the section is complete, return to the multiple choice question to choose another answer.